# database query possibility?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

1)access password from 3 (student,teacher,alumni)tables if given mail id matches to their mail id

2) i want to write only one program for password recovery for these three users

the code for accessing one password from one table is

```
 select password from current_student where mail_Id='"+mail_Id+"'
```

another code

```
(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM current_student HAVING mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM dept_Staff HAVING mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM  alumni HAVING mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com')
```

and the error message is

```
Query: (select password as r_password,mail_Id as r_mail_Id from current_student HAVING mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION (selec...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') 
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1
```

Comment: You can use joins for multiple table queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something like this:

```
(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id FROM current_student HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION
(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id FROM dept_Staff HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION
(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com')
```

YOUR_TABLE_NAME >> Change this table name with your respective table name.

Comment: can we write having without group by in sql query? @prits

Comment: May be i didnt get your question. Where is `group by` in above query? What is your exact requirement?

Comment: Check my edited answer. If it didnt worked let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: the code you told i have added in the questionj with error message @prits

Comment: problem is in `having` clause as per your query use should use `r_mail_Id` and not `mail_Id`, try this `(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM current_student HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM dept_Staff HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM your_table_name  HAVING r_mail_Id = 'mahender0791@gmail.com')`

Comment: Also replace `your_table_name` in my above comment by the table name which you need. Check my edited answer again.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM current_student HAVING r_mail_Id = 'xx') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM dept_Staff HAVING r_mail_Id = 'xx') UNION (SELECT PASSWORD AS r_password,mail_Id AS r_mail_Id  FROM alumni HAVING r_mail_Id = 'xx')
```

this will work